# Changing image source in xaml with trigger does not work properly

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, triggers

I need to change image in toolbar according to some boolean property in my viewModel. I am using trigger to change image source. Is it the right way? My code is not running properly, sometimes it works, but sometimes the image stay unchanged.

```
<Image x:Key="startPauseResumeAnalysisToolbarImage" >
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/ToolbarIcons/play.png" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAnalysisRunning}" Value="True" >
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/ToolbarIcons/pause.png"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: I also have this problem, it doesn't seem to flip.

Answer (score 6):

It should work. Difficult to see why it does not without the rest of the code. Are you implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in whatever class has the IsAnalysisRunning property?

Here is a small sample i used to test this:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    <Image >
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="Desert.jpg" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAnalysisRunning}" Value="True" >
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Koala.jpg"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,12,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
    private bool _isAnalysisRunning = false;
    public bool IsAnalysisRunning
    {
        get { return _isAnalysisRunning; }
        set {
            _isAnalysisRunning = value;
            NotifyPropretyChanged("IsAnalysisRunning");
        }
    }
    private void NotifyPropretyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsAnalysisRunning = !IsAnalysisRunning;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day !

Comment: Thank you so much, saved my day and night as well ;)